# Using bind_result AND store_result in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysqli login script that works fine here:

```
if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])) {
  $loginCheck = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT cms_user, cms_email FROM cms_accounts WHERE cms_email=? AND cms_password=?');
  $loginCheck->bind_param('ss',$_POST['loginEmail'],sha1($_POST['loginPass']));
  $loginCheck->execute();

  $loginCheck->store_result();
  if ($loginCheck->num_rows > 0) { 
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = '1'; 
  }
  else { $loginFail = true; }

  $loginCheck->close();
}
```

Now I want to add the data selected in the query to other session variables. So I add `bind_result()` and `fetch()` like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])) {
    $loginCheck = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT cms_user, cms_email FROM cms_accounts WHERE cms_email=? AND cms_password=?');
    $loginCheck->bind_param('ss',$_POST['loginEmail'],sha1($_POST['loginPass']));
    $loginCheck->execute();

    $loginCheck->bind_result($loginUser,$loginEmail);
    $loginCheck->fetch();
    $loginCheck->store_result();
    if ($loginCheck->num_rows > 0) { 
      $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = '1'; 
      $_SESSION['loginUser'] = $loginUser;
      $_SESSION['loginEmail'] = $loginEmail; 
    }
    else { $loginFail = true; }

    $loginCheck->close();
  }
```

All of a sudden the login fails. Is it possible to have `store_result()` and `bind_result()` in the same query? Is there an order to write them in?

Comment: I think this `$loginCheck->store_result();` is causing your issue, you don't need it. just remove it and test, I can't see any other issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work for me. The login isn't actually working at all anymore.

Comment: are you sure your query returns is running and returning results? echo your query, and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: If I remove the bind_result and fetch, the login works fine. So there's something wrong with creating those variables and putting them in a session ID. I assumed it was to do with the way I had written it or the order it was in...

Comment: Your order is fine, this `$loginCheck->store_result();` should be on the the line over `$loginCheck->bind_result();` if you want ot keep it

Comment: That fixed it! So it was the order I'd written the `bind_result()` and `store_result()`. `store_result()` must go first. Feel free to write as an answer for points..

Comment: all good it is about helping not the points :)